# Why does SDL_GetWindowWMInfo() require SDL version?

Tags: sdl-2

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowWMInfo) for

```c
SDL_bool SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(SDL_Window*    window,
                             SDL_SysWMinfo* info)
```

`SDL_SysWMinfo* info`'s `SDL_Version version` member must be defined by the `SDL_VERSION` macro at compile time before it is passed.

Why does `SDL_GetWindowWMInfo` require the SDL version the calling code was compiled against? What would happen if `SDL_GetWindowWMInfo` did not check the SDL version?

Comment: The video implementations check if they're part of the same SDL version as the original caller (e.g. [`WIN_GetWindowWMInfo`](https://github.com/soulik/libsdl2/blob/1e51e5a6b046031302b00fddeafcac04ccd5926e/src/video/windows/SDL_windowswindow.c#L642), [`X11_GetWindowWMInfo`](https://github.com/soulik/libsdl2/blob/1e51e5a6b046031302b00fddeafcac04ccd5926e/src/video/x11/SDL_x11window.c#L1412)). I'm not sure why that is, though, because I've never seen those implementations isolated in separate binaries. Also, I'd think that `SDL_GetWindowWMInfo` could do that by itself.

Comment: If SDL gets updated (without recompiling a program, just a dynamic library) with new video implementation and its exposes more data through SysWMinfo (hence union size of SysWMinfo increases) - this call will stomp memory as it will try to write more bytes than was allocated. Or layout of existing video system changes. It does not seem to be very good protection though, as at best it will just fail to fill info structure, although I've seen said memory stomping in the wild anyway.

Comment: Why can't the linker catch these kinds of things?

Comment: Not very realistic, not without redefining the entire compilation and linking process. Linker operates mostly upon function names; incorproating actual types would be very costly, both in terms of file sizes and runtime performance (i.e. shared libraries - will result in longer program startup). Compiler have required info, but it is lost after translation; if you have two translation units with different structure layouts with the same name, both will compile and link without any warnings. Worse, somethimes it is exactly what programmer wanted.

Comment: @Rhymoid What would those implementation being isolated in separate binaries have to do with the SDL version?

Comment: If the video implementation is compiled into a separate binary, it can be packaged and deployed separately and end up being dynamically linked with the wrong SDL2 core library, which can't be detected by current dynamic linkers. This isn't really a problem when SDL2 is designed to be monolithic, though.

Comment: @Rhymoid well there may be a reason for that, but there is no implementation to back it. In theory driver impl may know what changed in which version and fill info differently (say don't fill extra fields that didn't exist in version X).

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much like keltar said.  This is from SDL_windowswindow.c:

```
SDL_bool
WIN_GetWindowWMInfo(_THIS, SDL_Window * window, SDL_SysWMinfo * info)
{
    const SDL_WindowData *data = (const SDL_WindowData *) window->driverdata;
    if (info->version.major <= SDL_MAJOR_VERSION) {
        info->subsystem = SDL_SYSWM_WINDOWS;
        info->info.win.window = data->hwnd;
        info->info.win.hdc = data->hdc;
        return SDL_TRUE;
    } else {
        SDL_SetError("Application not compiled with SDL %d.%d\n",
                     SDL_MAJOR_VERSION, SDL_MINOR_VERSION);
        return SDL_FALSE;
    }
}
```

This function fills in a user-provided struct.  The danger is that this struct is liable to change as the platform support in SDL changes (as opposed to actual feature/API changes that are more apparent in a new version number).

If that struct definition has changed between versions of SDL (say, you use updated headers but old dll), this requirement allows SDL to detect the problem before it stomps your program's memory.